# Insert Value From " Table Driver" Into "Table Booking" Using WHERE

Tags: mysql, insert

Insert Value From " Table Driver"
[image]

Into "Table Booking"  Using WHERE
[image]

I want to insert  one of values on column"Driver_Name" that i have choosen or random  From "table Driver"
 INTO column "Drv_Name" where the "Booking_Status=wait" 
on "Table Booking"

Comment: No images please. please paste the SQL that you executed and what was the outcome and what you expect output should be?

Comment: `that i have choosen or random`... what does this mean?  How are the two tables related?

Comment: Please tag database name

Answer (score 1):

```
 insert into Table2 select Column from Table1 where Condition
```